# How to get button from alertview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have radio button that added to `UIView` and view added to `alertview` using :

```
[alertHours setValue:viewHours forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Button sets with their `tag` so now i want to get all button in buttons action event, i used this code for retrieving all button :

```
for (int i = 111 ; i <= 117 ; i++){
    UIButton *btnSender = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    [btnSender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

but can't get button using this, i've also used this :

```
UIButton *btnSender = (UIButton*)[alertObject viewWithTag:i];
```

but same, can't get button.

How i can get all button in action method ?

Comment: view hours is your view or your button bro..

Comment: buttons are added to viewHours and viewHours added to alertview.

Comment: viewhours are your UIView correct

Comment: Do you use alertView for iOS 8 or iOS 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
UIButton *btnSender = (UIButton*)[viewHours viewWithTag:i];
```

Since the buttons are in the viewHours view.

Comment: `self.view` refer's to the view controller's main view. However since your buttons are inside the viewHours view, you should specify it as the view you're searching for. Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The standard syntax of your KVC code

```
[alertHours setValue:viewHours forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

is

```
alertHours.accessoryView = viewHours;
```

which is preferable unless KVC is explicitly involved.

It assigns `viewHours` to the `accessoryView` of the main view.
Therefore the buttons are subviews of the accessoryView == `viewHours` rather than `self.view`.

You could also write

```
UIButton *btnSender = (UIButton*)[alertHours.accessoryView viewWithTag:i];
```

Comment: Thx @vadian, than why alertObject.subviews is nil ?

Comment: Because the `accessoryView` is a special view and not part to the `subviews` array

Answer (score 0):

radio button that is added to UIView and view is added to alertview, so can try this,

```
UIButton *btnSender = (UIButton*)[alertObject.subviews viewWithTag:i];
```

Comment: alertObject.subviews is blank